# How to count distance to the previous zero in pandas series?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, series

I have the following pandas series (represented as a list):

```
[7,2,0,3,4,2,5,0,3,4]
```

I would like to define a new series that returns distance to the last zero. It means that I would like to have the following output:

```
[1,2,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2]
```

How to do it in pandas in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 9):

The complexity is `O(n)`. What will slow it down is doing a `for` loop in python. If there are `k` zeros in the series, and `log k` is negligibile comparing to the length of series, an `O(n log k)` solution would be:

```
>>> izero = np.r_[-1, (ts == 0).nonzero()[0]]  # indices of zeros
>>> idx = np.arange(len(ts))
>>> idx - izero[np.searchsorted(izero - 1, idx) - 1]
array([1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score 4):

A solution in Pandas is a little bit tricky, but could look like this (`s` is your Series):

```
>>> x = (s != 0).cumsum()
>>> y = x != x.shift()
>>> y.groupby((y != y.shift()).cumsum()).cumsum()
0    1
1    2
2    0
3    1
4    2
5    3
6    4
7    0
8    1
9    2
dtype: int64
```

For the last step, this uses the "itertools.groupby" recipe in the Pandas cookbook [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#grouping).

Comment: I admire the elegance, but this performs a large number of passes + a ``groupby``, for something that's so trivial to do in a single-pass Cython extension.

Comment: I agree - this type of thing is better off implemented in Cython if performance is important. It is possible to do in Pandas (as the cookbook shows), which is handy if  Cython is not an available option.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that may not be as performant (haven't really checked), but easier to understand in terms of the steps (at least for me), would be:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [7, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 4]})
df

df['flag'] = np.where(df['X'] == 0, 0, 1)
df['cumsum'] = df['flag'].cumsum()
df['offset'] = df['cumsum']
df.loc[df.flag==1, 'offset'] = np.nan
df['offset'] = df['offset'].fillna(method='ffill').fillna(0).astype(int)
df['final'] = df['cumsum'] - df['offset']

df
```

Answer (score 1):

It's sometimes surprising to see how simple it is to get c-like speeds for this stuff using [Cython](http://cython.org/). Assuming your column's `.values` gives `arr`, then:

```
cdef int[:, :, :] arr_view = arr
ret = np.zeros_like(arr)
cdef int[:, :, :] ret_view = ret

cdef int i, zero_count = 0
for i in range(len(ret)):
    zero_count = 0 if arr_view[i] == 0 else zero_count + 1
    ret_view[i] = zero_count
```

Note the use of [typed memory views](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html), which are extremely fast. You can speed it further using `@cython.boundscheck(False)` decorating a function using this.

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [7, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 4]})
zeros = np.r_[-1, np.where(df.X == 0)[0]]

def d0(a):
    return np.min(a[a>=0])
    
df.index.to_series().apply(lambda i: d0(i - zeros))
```

Or using pure numpy

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [7, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 4]})
a = np.arange(len(df))[:, None] - np.r_[-1 , np.where(df.X == 0)[0]][None]

np.min(a, where=a>=0, axis=1, initial=len(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe pandas is not the best tool for this as in the answer by @behzad.nouri, however here is another variation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [7, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 4]})

z = df.ne(0).X
z.groupby((z != z.shift()).cumsum()).cumsum()

0    1
1    2
2    0
3    1
4    2
5    3
6    4
7    0
8    1
9    2
Name: X, dtype: int64
```

**Solution 2:**

If you write the following code you will get almost everything you need, except that the first row starts from 0 and not 1:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [7, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 4]})
df.eq(0).cumsum().groupby('X').cumcount()

0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    2
5    3
6    4
7    0
8    1
9    2
dtype: int64
```

This happened because cumulative sum starts the counting from 0. To get the desired results, I added a 0 to the first row, calculated everything and then dropped the 0 at the end to get:

```
x = pd.Series([0], index=[0])
df = pd.concat([x, df])
df.eq(0).cumsum().groupby('X').cumcount().reset_index(drop=True).drop(0).reset_index(drop=True)

0    1
1    2
2    0
3    1
4    2
5    3
6    4
7    0
8    1
9    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do this using Numpy [`accumulate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html).  The only catch is, to initialize the counter at zero you need to insert a zero infront of the series values.

```
import numpy as np

# Define Python function
f = lambda a, b: 0 if b == 0 else a + 1

# Convert to Numpy ufunc
npf = np.frompyfunc(f, 2, 1)

# Apply recursively over series values
x = npf.accumulate(np.r_[0, s.values])[1:]

print(x)
```

```
array([1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way without using groupby:

```
((v:=pd.Series([7,2,0,3,4,2,5,0,3,4]).ne(0))
.cumsum()
.where(v.eq(0)).ffill().fillna(0)
.rsub(v.cumsum())
.astype(int)
.tolist())
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2]
```