# Pandas: compute oriented distance to the next true

Tags: python, pandas

I have a serie of true/false in a pandas data frame and I want to convert this column to a grandient with Negative values in False, positive values in true and insert 0 between a true and a false. 
The insertion of the zero should be something optional in my code.

Then the values should be incremented by -1 or +1 when the distance with the next transition true/false increase.

I am wordering how to write this in clean python code.

16/10/18: I added a new example at the end of my post that fails with the current answer.

so this:

```
0 False 
1 False
2 False
3 False
4 True
5 True
6 True
7 True
8 True 
9 True 
10 False
11 False 
12 False 
13 False 
14 False 
15 True 
16 True 
17 True 
18 True 
19 True 
20 False
```

Would give:

```
0 False=> -4
1 False=> -3
2 False=> -2
3 False=> -1
=>0  
4 True =>+1
5 True => +2
6 True=> +3
7 True=> +3
8 True => +2
9 True => +1
=>0
10 False =>-1
11 False => -2
12 False => -3
13 False =>-2
14 False => -1
=>0
15 True =>+1
16 True =>+2
17 True =>+3
18 True =>+2
19 True =>+1
=>0
20 False=>-1
```

Here is another example:
For example here

```
False
False
False
False
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False`
```

Which should gives:

```
0     -4
1     -3
2     -2
3     -1
4      1
5      2
6      3
7      4
8      5
9      5
10     4
11     3
12     2
13     1
14    -1
15    -2
16    -3
17    -4
18    -5
19    -6
20    -7
21    -8
22    -9
23    -10
```

My question is very similar to this one :[How to count distance to the previous zero in pandas series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730981/how-to-count-distance-to-the-previous-zero-in-pandas-series)

Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge.

Edit: the answer from RafaelC does not work as it gives with the second example the following result:

```
0     -4
1     -3
2     -2
3     -1
4      1
5      2
6      3
7      4
8      5
9      5
10     4
11     3
12     2
13     1
14   -10
15    -9
16    -8
17    -7
18    -6
19    -5
20    -4
21    -3
22    -2
23    -1
```

At index 14, it gives -10 instead of -1

Edit/edit: 
The last answer from RaphaelC is not working in this case:

```
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
True
True
True
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
```

The function returns as error:

```
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in transform(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
   3659 
   3660             indexer = self._get_index(name)
-> 3661             s = klass(res, indexer)
   3662             results.append(s)
   3663 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    259                             'Length of passed values is {val}, '
    260                             'index implies {ind}'
--> 261                             .format(val=len(data), ind=len(index)))
    262                 except TypeError:
    263                     pass

ValueError: Length of passed values is 2, index implies 3
```

And I do not understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, by definition, values will be a gradient if they are in the middle of the data frame, and just a reverse range if they are the first or last group.

```
g = df.groupby((df.col != df.col.shift()).cumsum())
n_groups = len(g)

def f(s):
    n = len(s)//2
    t = s.all().all()
    if s.name == 1:
        x = list(range(len(s), 0, -1))
    elif s.name == n_groups:
        x = list(range(1, len(s)+1))
    else:
        x = list(range(1,n+1)) + list(range(n if n!=1 else n+1,0,-1))
        if n%2 == 0: x.insert(n,n+1)
    return pd.Series(x) * (1 if t else -1)

g['col'].transform(f).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Yields

```
0    -4
1    -3
2    -2
3    -1
4     1
5     2
6     3
7     3
8     2
9     1
10   -1
11   -2
12   -3
13   -2
14   -1
15    1
16    2
17    3
18    2
19    1
20   -1
```

and

```
0     -4
1     -3
2     -2
3     -1
4      1
5      2
6      3
7      4
8      5
9      5
10     4
11     3
12     2
13     1
14    -1
15    -2
16    -3
17    -4
18    -5
19    -6
20    -7
21    -8
22    -9
23   -10
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately it does not work as expected. I added a second example where the code above fails. Maybe my question was not very clear. Sorry for that

Comment: @tommy123 thats just a small detail to fix. Look at  edited code

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, greatly appreciate.